# Resizing image to fit responsive column cell using css

Tags: html, css

I am using a responsive column format to create my mobile website. The content of each column is formed using images that I wish to fill 100% width and auto resize the height.

I have tried max-width:100% and max-height:100% and it will not fill the image width to 100% of the column area. This solution resizes the column height to meet the image, but will not resize the image to meet 100% of the column width.

Source code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column" id="column1">
        <img id="top_block_graphic" src="graphics/top-block.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
grid-gap: 7px;
clear: both;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 1.6em;
width: 100%;
}

.column {
background-color: rgba(173,167,133,0.5);
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#column1 {
grid-column: 1/3;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 35.66% 0 0 0;
}

#top_block_graphic {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: #column1 img{ width:100%; } ?

Comment: #column1 img is #top_block_graphic

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
#column1 {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

**Or this:**

```
#column1 {
  width: 100vw !important;
  height: auto !important; /* 100vh */
}
```

Comment: Still not resizing image to 100% width.

Comment: you have this code: <div class="column" id="column1"><img id="top_block_graphic" src="graphics/top-block.png" alt=""/>
</div> inside in other DIV?

Comment: yes. it is in a container div that houses the other column elements to create a grid look.

Comment: You have to modify the width of the father div first.

Comment: I have updated the code to include the parent divs code